# Clicking a Button Inside a UserControl won't fire the UserControls MouseDown Event

Tags: c#, wpf, events, event-handling

I have a `Page`, inside I generate a few copies of a `UserControl`. The page is supposed to do stuff
when the `UserControl_MouseDown` **event** is fired. Everything works fine until the user clickes 
on a part of the `UserControl` where a `Control` is present. As you would expect, the `Control`
prevents the `UserControl_MouseDown` event to fire.

**Page**

```
//Fired when the StackPanel is clicked but not when the TextBox is.
private void UserControl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

**UserControl**

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Maybe useful: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/227733/Passing-events-from-child-to-parent-controls-built

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As controls tend to swallow events you could rather use the `PreviewMouseDown`-Event:

```
<UserControl PreviewMouseDown="UserControl_MouseDown">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.previewmousedown?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: ach, no that's not what I meant.

Comment: Ah I think I now know what you tried to ask. Do you have the `UserControl_MouseDown` in your `<UserControl MouseDown="UserControl_MouseDown">`? I missed that, sorry. Yeah the event should span all over the User Control obviously. You should use the PreviewMouseDown-Event instead as it won't be "swallowed" by controls. I'll update the answer.